# Sampling from an density raised to a non-integer power (also, is this a reasonable thing to think about?)

Tags: sampling, density-function, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a density that can be written as follows,

$$
p(\mathbf{z}) = \frac{1}{H_f}\prod_iq_i(\mathbf{z})
$$

I want to sample from the density $p(\mathbf{z})$ using samples from each of $q_i(\mathbf{z})$, and there are a bunch of algorithms that let me do this, according to the answer to this question here - [Previous similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171237/product-of-k-independent-densities)

In those solutions, we are required to draw samples from $q_i(\mathbf{z})$.  In the problem I am faced with, my $q_i(\mathbf{z})$ has the following form

$$
q_i(\mathbf{z}) = [h_i(\mathbf{z})]^{\alpha_i}
$$
where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ so the overall density can be written as
$$
p(\mathbf{z}) = \frac{1}{H_f}\prod_i[h_i(\mathbf{z})]^{\alpha_i}
$$
I know how to sample from $h_i(\mathbf{z})$ without MCMC techniques - $h_i(\mathbf{z})$ is an exponential family distribution that I have chosen such that I can sample from it easily

My question is as follows

1. How do I sample from the unnormalised density $[h_i(\mathbf{z})]^{\alpha_i}$, given I can sample from $h_i(\mathbf{z})$

2.Can I still use the kind of techniques in the above reference?

3.Are there more modern approaches that aren't direct followups from the papers in that question?

Comment: The question is unclear to me because, mathematically,$$g(q_1(z)^{\alpha_1},\ldots,q_n(z)^{\alpha_n})=f(q_1(z),\ldots,q_n(z))$$

Comment: Fair point, I will edit the question and I hope this clarifies

Comment: I still cannot make sense of this question, because your mathematical formulation does not appear to describe what is usually known as a mixture and it is too general to permit a solution.

Comment: I shall give an exact example and hope that is workable

Comment: @whuber I have rewritten the question to try and resolve your problems with it.

Comment: If $h(z)$ is an exponential family density, so is $h^{\alpha_i}(z)$.

Comment: Oh - that doesn't make sense to me, I'm afraid - can you clarify?  If $h_{i}^{\alpha_i}(\mathbf{z}) = (\exp(\eta^{T}\psi(\mathbf{z}) - \Phi(\mathbf{\eta}))\nu(\mathbf{z}))^{\alpha_i} = \exp(\alpha_i\eta^{T}\psi(\mathbf{z}) - \alpha_i\Phi(\mathbf{\eta}))(\nu(\mathbf{z})^{\alpha_i})$, its surprising to me that this density is normalised, and the terms in the exponential don't appear to fit the normal structure.  Can you explain to me an intuitive reason why this holds?  If it does, I suppose the question is whether the technique for the original ExpFam density carry across to the new one?